# During fork system call which execute first parent or child

Tags: c, process, forking

As i am executing a one pipe example pgm from libc.pdf,I noticed that the parent process first completed then only child process completed.From my knowledged about os the child process must complete before the parent completes.so what happens here

Comment: If there was a deterministic answer to this question, what would be the point of forking off a new process?

Comment: Are you sure to be *exactly* able to define what does "execute first" means?

Comment: Not a software engineering or design question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot know, and on a multi-core system both processes could run simultaneously (on different cores). Notice that [preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) (and [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)) can happen at *any* time (even "in the middle" of a C statement, compiled to a dozen of [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) instrutions), be it on a single-core system (very rare today) or a multi-core one, because [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) making preemption and context switches occur at any machine code instruction.

<sup>(you should think as if (when `fork` succeeds) both parent and child are running *exactly simultaneously*; what is actually happening is an unimportant, and difficult to observe, implementation detail)</sup>

Read wikipage on [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29), then read *carefully* man page [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) which has several chapters about forking and processes. Read also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). On Linux, run `cat /proc/interrupts` a few times (read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) to understand how often context switches happen (usually every few milliseconds).

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Comment: Even on a single core system, time slicing could result in a non-deterministic processing order. In general, you cannot make assumptions about the relative ordering of instructions in different threads or processes unless you enforce it with mutexes or semaphores.

Answer (score -3):

On most systems, the child executes first. This is to avoid the overhead that comes with copy on write, since the parent does not write to the address space.

Comment: Completely wrong in general

Comment: There is no "X executes before Y" relation between parent and child processes (as there is with normal functions where "*callee* executes before the *caller*). Processes are executed concurrently (at least conceptually). As @BasileStarynkevitch noted, this is a completely bogus answer.